# WebSockets streaming third party API to multiple subclients

Tags: javascript, php, api, websocket, data-driven

We have a data-driven application where our backend continuously fetches data from a third party server and then feeds it over websocket to our clients frontend. Now the issue is that whenever each client will come the same data has to be fetched twice for both of them which is deemed unnecessary.
Suppose the following code (in PHP for example)

```
$apiData = file_get_contents('https://third-party-api.com/feed/data.json');
$sockets->send($apiData);
```

Now our client on frontend can request this data via websockets.But the issue is if the second client connects, then the same data is downloaded twice.

Note:
We do not want to save data (no database or anything at all because its of no use to save data).

Is there a method where if two clients are connected then the same feed can be sent to both of them?

Comment: Well if you want to send it to two clients who are not both connected at the time the data is fetched then you'll need to cache the data somewhere

Comment: Actually we do not need to cache data because the feed is always real-time and changing constantly and old data is always disregarded, so its like when one client is connected the pipe opens to the API server, now whenever further clients are connected they are given data from the client-1's pipe instead of new.

Comment: There is no "pipe" to the API server though, because you're connecting to the API using HTTP, so it's a one-off request-response scenario. The connection is opened, you receive the data all at once, and then the connection closes again immediately. It does not create an ongoing stream or connection (unlike websockets!). Therefore if you want to re-use the data which was originally requested for client 1 and show it to other clients, you need to cache it somewhere. Either that or you have to go back to your original scenario and download it again from the API.

Comment: Got it, redis would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the data from the API it to two clients who are not both connected at the time the data is fetched then you'll need to cache the data somewhere

For example a Redis cache (or similar technology) is one option if you don't want to use a database or other persistent storage.